# Azure SFTP Connector, Unable to edit App Settings values once created

Tags: powershell, azure, appsettings, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I created an SFTP Connector in Azure Portal , once configured 'Root Folder' and 'IP address' of the ftp server I was unable to edit its values in the App Settings. The Save Icon in top bar is disabled in the Applications Settings Blade.

However I can change it via PowerShell script but when I try to edit key value pairs of App Settings in the Applications Settings Blade, The Save button remains disabled even If I enter new Key/Value pair in the App Settings or delete any of them. I also try reloading the portal but in vain.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you using the "old" version of logic apps, or the refresh version of februari: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/logic-apps-preview-refresh-released/

Comment: And to confirm, I can't save them as well in the old logic apps on the blade. In the new version I encounter other errors when trying to change settings: error executing the api /datasets/default/folders/6e202211-2856-4d17-9ded-5beb8b8626b0

Comment: Yes I'm using preview version of SFTP Connector api app not logic app. It was working fine with preview version of the Logic apps before I tried to edit its app settings. Microsoft has released new  version of Logic apps but would api app be working on the same older version?

Comment: Not sure about mixing the 2 versions

Answer (score 1):

With the latest February preview version of release there is a new concept called "connection" entity, which should be configured before using the new connectors. Basically appsettings are exposed through connections and are being used by the connectors during runtime, hence I would suggest try checking all the connection properties are configured correctly.
**Erik Oppedijk** It will be great if you can provide some more info of the scenario you are trying out and where is it failing.

Comment: Thanks TusharJ for the add but all settings have been configured properly and they were working fine with older sftp connector configurations.

Comment: @Tushar, when I create a new SFTP connector, enter all details, enter a folder and save. Now open the folder settings (I press "...") I see SFTP, I click on the ">" for more details, it says "loading" and fails with the "error executing the api /datasets/default/folders/6e202211-2856-4d17-9ded-5beb8b8626b0" error

Comment: @ErikOppedijk Can you follow the same steps as you mentioned above with only one modification in it. Press F12 -> Network make sure capturing traffic is enabled before you click ">". Share the screenshot or the capture log with me. Can you drop me a mail at tushar.jamgaonkar@hotmail.com

Comment: Info mailed, a 401 with the JSON call

Comment: This is resolved. @ErikOppedijk was able to use the Sftp connector with correct connection creds.

Comment: Where does one find this new "connection" entity? I can't find where to edit any of the connection properties for the connectors in my Logic App

Comment: @ChrisHarrington you can use powershell to do this till the ui for management is ready refer this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/03/18/using-powershell-to-manage-api-connections/